# Image viewport with zoom in Javascript

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, javascript

I want to display a huge image inside a viewport in a html page. I would like to be able to drag and drop the image to move it inside the viewport, like in Google Maps.

Any library where I can find such component?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dupe. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763203/turning-a-div-into-a-click-and-drag-viewport

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find it first time when I tried to find for dupes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this bad boy out --> http://www.ajax-zoom.com/

**EDIT**

If that doesn't float your boat, look at this --> http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/mapbox/

Comment: ajax-zoom is php dependant, unfortunately.

Comment: yep, your edit is more portable, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [SeaDragon](http://www.seadragon.com/).  The technology and interface work really well. Follow the [developer link](http://www.seadragon.com/developer/) for lots of options.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using .dzi files and use directly .jpg files? The tool seems really good, but the fact that uses .dzi is annoying :(

Comment: @pakore: Agreed.  Their implementation is good, but I never got beyond putting jpg's on their server and then embedding them on a page.  Works nicely for super-large images, but the solutions suggested in the other answer may suit your needs better.

Answer (score -1):

You can try out using simple javascript window objects such as the mouse pointer locator and then use it to change the background position of your image that would inturn act as a magnified image. 
Here is the complete tutorial : http://www.hklabs.org/articles/image_zooming_with_javascript

Comment: Rather than requiring us to click through to your blog post, could you post the relevant information within your answer here? We prefer for answers to be self-contained.

Comment: LInk is no longer working.